# jq: Find a key in a struct in an array or use default value in jq

Tags: jq

Consider this JSON input:

```
{
  "id":0,
  "Tags": [
    {"Key":"Name", "Value":"machine1"},
    {"Key":"Stage", "Value":"UAT"}
  ]
},
{
  "id":1,
  "Tags": [
    {"Key":"Stage", "Value":"UAT"}
  ]
},
{
  "id":2,
  "Tags": []
},
{
  "id":3
}
```

I seek a solution that after piping and selects will yield either the value of the `Value` field where a key `Name` is `Name` or `(none)` as a default.  The closest I get is:

```
jq -r 'if(.Tags == null or .Tags == []) then .Tags=[{"Key":"Name","Value":"(none)"}] else . end | "\(.id) \(.Tags[] | select(.Key == "Name")|.Value)" '
```

The solution works for id 0, 2, and 3.   It is when the `Tags` array exists but does *not* contain .Key == "Name" that the select yields null and no value is returned.  If I jiggle around with this a little more I can probably stumble into it but.   Ideally I want to do something like this (jq pseudocode):

```
Defend against null tags, then walk array looking for Name
'\(.Tags // [{}] | select(.Tags[].Key == "Name")?.Value // "(none)")
```

It might just be that I do need 1 more stage but I want to explore other clever possibilities.

Comment: Your sample JSON input seems to be invalid (I get `jq: parse error: Expected value before ',' at line 7, column 2`). Did you mean to write it without commas separating the objects?

Comment: To parse comma-delimited JSON with the delimiting commas on separate lines, see the jq FAQ (look for: `def iterate(f): def r: f | (., r); r;`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `jq` script should do the trick:

```
{
  id,
  name: (first(.Tags[] | select(.Key == "Name").Value)? // "(none)")
}
| "\(.id) \(.name)"
```

It works similar to your pseudocode, but it doesn't proactively defend against the `.Tags` array being absent or empty. There's no particular reason to treat that differently than the case where it exists but doesn't contain a `Name` entry. This program just tries to access `.Value` of the `Name` entry, and if that doesn't work for any reason at all, it substitutes `"(none)"`.

You can use this either by putting it in a file, or directly with

```
$ jq -r '{id, name: ...} | "\(.id) \(.name)"' input.json
```

Comment: Ah, yes!  Pack all the opptys for failure into one ?-protected expression and if any of them fail, go with the default.    Excellent use of `first` to create the package for ? vs. just a piar of wrapper () and in fact there should be only one Key = Name entry.